# Python: "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Tags: python, string, list

I am making a backup program on Python. It gives me this error 'can only concatenate list (not "str") to list' all the time.

I tried to make some changes, but it didn't work. Tried to change the path to the backup file.

```
import os
import time

source = ['C:\\OSPanel']

targetdir = ['C:\\Backup']

target = targetdir + os.sep + time.strftime() + '.zip'

zipcommand = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zipcommand) == 0:
    print ("Backup copy has been saved in", target)
else:
    print ("Can't backup")
```

I expect the output - "Backup copy has been saved in..."
But I just get this, error.

Comment: you're adding a list to a string. That makes no sense. `targetdir + os.sep...`

Comment: Can you explain what do I need to change? Anyways thank you

Comment: To be more clear, `targetdir` is a list but `os.sep` is a string (backslash on windows and slash on everything else). You can't add them with `+`. Why did you stuff the target directory in a list?

Comment: Ok, ok. Now I get it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
source = ["C:\\src"]
target = ["C:\\treg"]
import os, time, datatetime
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
td = [ os.path.join(t, now + '.zip') for t in target]
>>> td
['C:\\treg\\08_18_2019_15_20_28.zip']

...
```

Comment: welcome, if u want to know what code is doing use interactive python, do printouts or debug

Comment: I did, that is epic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
import os

from datetime import datetime
source = 'C:\\OSPanel'

targetdir = 'C:\\Backup'

now = datetime.now()

target = targetdir + os.sep + now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + '.zip'

zipcommand = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zipcommand) == 0:
    print ("Backup copy has been saved in", target)
else:
    print ("Can't backup")
```

Comment: Omg, thank you. Now I get it, I didn't even expect that someone will reply so fast.

Comment: Your upvote and check is welcome :)